# Can go object components talk to each others in composite pattern?

Tags: go, composite

I am trying to implement composite design pattern. I understood how to compose an object of object. In this example I have an athlete and the swim function.

```
type Athlete struct {
    name string
}

type CompositeAthlete struct {
    athlete Athlete
    Train   func(name string)
}
```

But if I need to pass the name after composed object creation:

```
    comp := CompositeAthlete{
        athlete: athlete,
        Train:   Swim,
    }
    comp.Train(athlete.name)
```

Is it possible to inject a method that is able to read inside the object where is injected;

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Athlete struct {
    name string
}

type CompositeAthlete struct {
    athlete Athlete
    Train   func(name string)
}

func (a *Athlete) Train() {
    fmt.Println("training ...")
}

func Swim(name string) {
    fmt.Println(strings.Join([]string{
        name,
        " is swimming",
    }, ""))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("vim-go")

    athlete := Athlete{"Mariottide"}
    athlete.Train()

    comp := CompositeAthlete{
        athlete: athlete,
        Train:   Swim,
    }
    comp.Train(athlete.name)
}
```

I would like that `comp` as composed object should not receive name from outside, but from athlete. IS it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can declare a `Train()` method for `CompositeAthlete`, and that method would have access to all `CompositeAthlete` fields (the function and the `athlete`).

Then you can use the function from inside the method.

Here's how you'd implement it, to make it more clear.

**CompositeAthlete definition**

(note that I have changed the field to `TrainFunc` so that it does not conflict with the method name)

```
type CompositeAthlete struct {
    athlete Athlete
    TrainFunc   func(name string)
}
```

Then the `Train()` method would just do:

```
func (c *CompositeAthlete) Train() {
    c.TrainFunc(c.athlete.name)
}
```

And you would use it almost the same as before (only the field name has changed):

```
comp := CompositeAthlete{
    athlete: athlete,
    TrainFunc:   Swim,
}
comp.Train()
```

See it working in this playground:

https://play.golang.org/p/xibH_tFers